# System.AccessViolationException at InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app, and it keeps crashing at the `InitializeComponent();` call with the error message: `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'`

Here's my code for this class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace esheets_trafalgareng
{
    public sealed partial class Tasks : Page
    {
        public static List<Button> Buttons { get; set; }
        public static Button SelectedButton;

        public Tasks()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Buttons = new List<Button>();
            foreach (Button button in secondaryContainer.Children.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (button.Name == "myTasks") SelectedButton = button;
                Buttons.Add(button);
            }
            if (SelectedButton != null) SelectedButton.isPressed = true;
            UpdateTheme();
        }

        public void TaskListChanged(Button button)
        {
            UpdateTheme();
        }

        private void UpdateTheme()
        {
            if (Theme.IsLight()) SetLightTheme();
            else SetDarkTheme();
        }

        private void SetLightTheme()
        {
            //Theme.UseImmersiveDarkMode(this.handle, false);

            primaryContainer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Theme.LightMain);
            primaryContainer.PaneBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Theme.LightSide);
        }

        private void SetDarkTheme()
        {
            //Theme.UseImmersiveDarkMode(this.handle, true);

            primaryContainer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Theme.DarkMain);
            primaryContainer.PaneBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Theme.DarkSide);
        }

        internal void AddButton(Button button)
        {
            secondaryContainer.Children.Add(button);
            Buttons.Add(button);
        }
    }
}
```

And my XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="esheets_trafalgareng.Tasks"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:esheets_trafalgareng"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <SplitView x:Name="primaryContainer" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsPaneOpen="True">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <StackPanel x:Name="secondaryContainer">
                    <local:PersonalButton x:Name="personalButton" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="54"/>
                    <local:Button x:Name="myTasks" Content="My Tasks" Margin="10,90,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="36" ImageOnly="False" IsList="True"/>
                    <local:Button x:Name="assignedToMe"  Content="Assigned To Me" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ImageOnly="False" IsList="True"/>
                    <local:Button x:Name="addList" Margin="0,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ImageOnly="True" IsList="False"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </SplitView.Pane>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The Button and PersonalButton components are custom components and I've put their code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using static esheets_trafalgareng.ImageOnlySettings;

namespace esheets_trafalgareng
{
    public partial class Button : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
    {
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Will determine whether the button only has an image or not")]
        internal Mode ImageOnly { get; set; }

        [Category("Common")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Will determine whether the button will be used as a list or not")]
        internal Mode IsList { get; set; }

        internal readonly List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        internal static int listCounter = 0;

        private static new Windows.UI.Color Background
        {
            get
            {
                if (Theme.IsLight()) return Theme.LightSide;
                else return Theme.DarkSide;
            }
        }
        private static new Windows.UI.Color Foreground
        {
            get
            {
                if (Theme.IsLight()) return Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
                else return Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            }
        }
        private static readonly Windows.UI.Color LightHover = Theme.LightButtonHover;
        private static readonly Windows.UI.Color DarkHover = Theme.DarkButtonHover;

        private static readonly int FontHeight = 10;
        //private static readonly Font ButtonFont = new Font(new FontFamily("Roboto"), FontHeight, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

        private bool isHover = false;
        public bool isPressed = false;

        public Button()
        {
            AddEvents();
        }

        private void AddEvents()
        {
            PointerEntered += Button_PointerEntered;
            PointerExited += Button_PointerExited;
            PointerPressed += Button_PointerPressed;
        }

        private Tasks GetTopParent()
        {
            Control c = this;
            while (c.Parent != null)
            {
                c = (Control)c.Parent;
            }
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Tasks)) return (Tasks)c;
            else return null;
        }

        private void Button_PointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsList == Mode.True)
            {
                isPressed = true;
                Tasks.SelectedButton.isPressed = false;
                Tasks.SelectedButton = this;
                GetTopParent().TaskListChanged(this);
            }
            else
            {
                Button b = new Button
                {
                    Margin = Margin,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment,
                    Width = Width,
                    Height = Height,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment,
                    ImageOnly = Mode.False,
                    IsList = Mode.True
                };
                Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(10, b.Margin.Bottom + 10, 10, 10);
                GetTopParent().AddButton(b);
            }
        }

        private void Button_PointerExited(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isHover = false;
        }

        private void Button_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isHover = true;
        }

        private Windows.UI.Color ButtonColor()
        {
            if (Theme.IsLight()) return isHover || isPressed ? LightHover : Background;
            return isHover || isPressed ? DarkHover : Background;
        }

        // OnPaint

    }

    internal class ImageOnlySettings
    {
        [Serializable]
        internal enum Mode
        {
            True,
            False
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace esheets_trafalgareng
{
    public sealed class PersonalButton : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
    {
        private static new Color Background
        {
            get
            {
                if (Theme.IsLight()) return Theme.LightSide;
                else return Theme.DarkSide;
            }
        }
        private static new Color Foreground
        {
            get
            {
                if (Theme.IsLight()) return Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
                else return Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            }
        }
        private static Color SecondaryForeground
        {
            get
            {
                if (Theme.IsLight()) return Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
                else return Color.FromArgb(0, 207, 207, 207);
            }
        }
        private static readonly Color LightHover = Theme.LightButtonHover;
        private static readonly Color DarkHover = Theme.DarkButtonHover;

        /*private static new readonly int FontHeight = 10;
        private static readonly Font NameFont = new Font("Roboto", FontHeight, FontStyle.Bold);
        private static readonly Font EmailFont = new Font("Roboto", FontHeight - 1);*/

        private bool isHover = false;
        private string name;
        private string email;

        public PersonalButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(PersonalButton);
            AddEvents();
        }

        private void AddEvents()
        {
            PointerEntered += OnPointerEntered;
            PointerExited += OnPointerExited;
            PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
        }

        private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void OnPointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isHover = false;
        }

        public void OnPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isHover = true;
        }

        private Color ButtonColor()
        {
            if (Theme.IsLight()) return isHover ? LightHover : Background;
            else return isHover ? DarkHover : Background;
        }

        // OnPaint


    }
}
```

Here's 2 other classes that I use, in case they are needed:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

namespace esheets_trafalgareng
{
    public class Theme
    {
        internal static readonly int Light = 0;
        internal static readonly int Dark = 1;

        internal static readonly Color LightSide = Color.FromArgb(0, 208, 208, 208);
        internal static readonly Color LightTask = Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 239, 243);
        internal static readonly Color LightButtonHover = Color.FromArgb(0, 201, 201, 201);
        internal static Color LightMain
        {
            get
            {
                if (Tasks.SelectedButton.Name == "myTasks") return Color.FromArgb(0, 98, 118, 196);
                else if (Tasks.SelectedButton.Name == "assignedToMe") return Color.FromArgb(0, 213, 241, 229);
                else return Color.FromArgb(0, 153, 51, 102);
            }
        }

        internal static readonly Color DarkSide = Color.FromArgb(0, 34, 34, 34);
        internal static readonly Color DarkTask = Color.FromArgb(0, 42, 42, 42);
        internal static readonly Color DarkButtonHover = Color.FromArgb(0, 50, 50, 50);
        internal static readonly Color DarkMain = Color.FromArgb(0, 28, 28, 28);

        internal static bool IsLight()
        {
            if (Options.Theme == Light)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (Options.Theme == Dark)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (UsingLightTheme())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        internal static bool UsingLightTheme()
        {
            UISettings DefaultTheme = new UISettings();
            string uiTheme = DefaultTheme.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Background).ToString();

            return uiTheme == "#FFFFFFFF";
        }

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);

        private const int DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE_BEFORE_20H1 = 19;
        private const int DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE = 20;

        internal static bool UseImmersiveDarkMode(IntPtr handle, bool enabled)
        {
            if (IsWindows10OrGreater(17763))
            {
                var attribute = DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE_BEFORE_20H1;
                if (IsWindows10OrGreater(18985))
                {
                    attribute = DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE;
                }

                int useImmersiveDarkMode = enabled ? 1 : 0;
                return DwmSetWindowAttribute(handle, attribute, ref useImmersiveDarkMode, sizeof(int)) == 0;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static bool IsWindows10OrGreater(int build = -1)
        {
            return Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 10 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= build;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace esheets_trafalgareng
{
    internal class Options
    {
        public static int Theme { get; set; } = 3;
        public static bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such a detailed code, but when I build, `Theme` is an unknown content. Could you please provide information about `Theme`? So that we can quickly build the project to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've just added the `Theme` class, as well as an `Options` class because it is also used. Hope it helps!

Comment: Post the *full* exception text, not just the message. The full exception, including the call stack, would show where exactly the error occurred and which chain of calls led to it. The relevant code is missing right now so the problem can't be reproduced. `InitializeComponents` is a method in the codebehind file where the controls are created. It's in the project itself, not some runtime method. To get an Access violation you'd have to use a custom control that somehow tried to execute unmanaged code and failed

Comment: If the exception shows that the error occurred inside `Theme`, which in turn is called by `PersonalButton`, it's probably because the unmanaged call to `DwmSetWindowAttribute` got bad data. Most likely the handle is NULL or invalid.

Comment: Posting all the code is *not* a good idea. You should post only the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem. It seems `UseImmersiveDarkMode` is called with a bad handle, but where is it called? Searching in this page shows only commented lines

Comment: I think the problem was with how I was defining my components, I am new to UWP and was just defining the components as classes, rather than user controls. I fixed that problem and that seemed to have also fixed this problem. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I figured out that the problem was that I was defining my components as C# classes rather than User Controls. If anyone else comes across this issue, make sure you have a `.xaml` and a `.cs.xaml` file for your components!